# DataTable for Object Not Woring

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using DataTables 1.13.5 and Laravel 10.0. I created a table with columns ID, Brand, First Name etc.

Also I have another column `all` whose type is JSON in my MySQL table. There are records like `zip` and its value. I have parsed the record.

My output: Initially One Record and on-hover show `all` Column.

Table details

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| brand | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| first_name | varchar(255) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| all | json | YES |  | NULL |  |
| created_at | timestamp | YES |  | NULL |  |

Table Values

| id | brand | first_name | all | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | test | [{"zip": "xyz", "phone": "123"}] | 2023-07-20 10:05:58 |
| 2 | Test | test | [{"zip": "abc", "phone": "456"}] | 2023-07-20 10:09:10 |

Script

```
var columnDefs = [

{
    title: "ID",
    targets: 0,
    render: function (data) {
        return (data['id']);
    }
},
{
    title: "Brand",
    targets: 1,
    render: function (data) {     
        return (data['brand']);
    }
},
{
    title: "Form",
    targets: 2,
    render: function (data) {
        return (data['form_name'];);
    }
},
{
    title: "First Name",
    targets: 3,
    render: function (data) {
        return (data['first_name']);
    }
},
{
    title: "All",
    targets: 4,
    className: 'all',
    render: function (data) {
        var details = JSON.parse(data['data']);
        var result = "";
        $.each(details, function (index, value) {
            $.each(value, function (v, k) {
                let underscore = v.replace('_', ' ');
                underscore = underscore.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function (letter) {
                    return letter.toUpperCase();
                });
                result = result + underscore + ": " + k + '<br>';
            });
        });
        return result;
    }
{
    title: "Created",
    targets: 5,
    render: function (data) {
        return (data['created_at']);
    }
},
```

Comment: what is exactly the problem? what you see and qhat you would like to see?

Comment: There is no such thing as a JSON Object. There is JSON, which is a textual format for storing and transmitting data. And there are JavaScript objects, which are data structures in memory. There is no JSON is your question.